# Numpy modifying rows by row indexes

Tags: python, numpy

I want to modify (in this case negate) several rows of a matrix given their indices, and keep the other rows intact.

```
A = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]])
indices = np.array([1, 2])
A_ = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [-4, -5, -6], [-7, -8, -9]])
```

What is the fastest way to achieve A_ from A and indices?

Comment: `A_[indices] *= -1`

Comment: Can you clarify, do you want to modify `A` or make a copy of `A` where specific rows are negated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with for loop

```
for i in indices:
    A[i] *=-1
```

with masking

```
A[indices] *= -1
```

Comment: Thanks - for loop is also the only thing that I can came up right now - is there any masking or filter-like approach that doesn't need for loops...?

Comment: hi, I edited my answer with a masking approach